# Why does java.util.TreeMap.KeySet not implement equals?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I would like to check if all keys of two TreeMaps are equal. By calling

```
myTreeMap.navigableKeySet()
```

I receive a `java.util.TreeMap.KeySet` which implements `NavigableSet` and this in turn extends `SortedSet`.
Hence I would expect that two KeySets are only considered equals if they do not only contain the same elements (as checked by equals of `AbstractSet`) but **also in the same order**. I can't see how this restriction is enforced by the class `KeySet`. What do I miss?

Comment: @fge `KeySet` is a package-private static inner class of `TreeMap`.

Comment: All `Set`s are contractually obligated to `equal` any other `Set` in any order, navigable, sorted, or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make that guarantee.

While `NavigableSet`, which extends `SortedSet`, guarantees that elements will be in the order defined by the elements themselves (if they implement `Comparable`) or the given `Comparator`, it does not override [`Set`'s contract for `.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). And `Set` makes no ordering guarantee.

You can have two `SortedSet`s with the same elements, but for which the comparison is different, they *will* be equal.

The only way you can check for element ordering is to slurp the elements of both sets into `List`s and check that these lists are equal -- because `List` [*does* guarantee element order in its `.equals()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Note that if the `KeySet` class did override `.equals()` (and therefore `.hashCode()` as well) to check for element order, it would no longer be able to pretend to implement `Set`!